# Is there a more efficient way to filter to a specific key rather than a prefix in this S3 rollback code?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have this code to rollback an S3 object to a specific version but there is no option for "key" in the method I'm using , only "prefix".  This is a problem because in this example i will end up delete all versions of objects named "questions copy".  So as you see, I had to filter in python, which seems less efficient.

```
import boto3
import logging
from operator import attrgetter

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())

def rollback_object(bucket, object_key, version_id):
    """
    Rolls back an object to an earlier version by deleting all versions that
    occurred after the specified rollback version.

    Usage is shown in the usage_demo_single_object function at the end of this module.

    :param bucket: The bucket that holds the object to roll back.
    :param object_key: The object to roll back.
    :param version_id: The version ID to roll back to.
    """
    # Versions must be sorted by last_modified date because delete markers are
    # at the end of the list even when they are interspersed in time. (This is because
    # when we use the builtin sorted method, it ensures this to be true. [if we sort ascending, then
    # the delete markers would always be on top])
    versions = sorted(
        bucket.object_versions.filter(Prefix=object_key), #note "prefix" means will delete "questions copy" if newer than version we are rolling back to.
        key=attrgetter("last_modified"), #note this code will also delete the delete marker if it is newer than the version we are rolling back to.
        reverse=True,
    )
    filtered_versions = [v for v in versions if v.key == object_key]

    logger.debug(
        "Got versions:\n%s",
        "\n".join(
            [
                f"\t{version.version_id}, last modified {version.last_modified}"
                for version in filtered_versions
            ]
        ),
    )

    if version_id in [ver.version_id for ver in filtered_versions]:
        print(f"Rolling back to version {version_id}")
        for version in filtered_versions:
            if version.version_id != version_id:
                version.delete()
                print(f"Deleted version {version.version_id}")
            else:
                break

        print(f"Active version is now {bucket.Object(object_key).version_id}")
    else:
        raise KeyError(
            f"{version_id} was not found in the list of versions for " f"{object_key}."
        )


if __name__ == '__main__':
   mybucket = boto3.resource('s3').Bucket('scottedwards2000') 
   result = rollback_object(mybucket, 'questions', 'RQY0ebFXtUnm.A48N2I62CEmdu2QZGEO')
   print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

So, the situation seems to be:

- It is not possible to request a list of versions for a specific object
- Instead, it is necessary to use `.object_versions` (or `list_object_versions()` for client calls), which returns versions for ALL objects in the bucket, but **can be filtered**
- The only form of filtering is by `Prefix`

You ask about efficiency. Since your code is written to only roll-back a single object, then it's not really possible to reduce the number of API calls to AWS. It could be more 'efficient' if *ALL* versions in the bucket were retrieved *once* and then you could determine the versions from the returned data. Similarly, it could be more efficient to use `delete_objects()` to delete multiple object versions in one API call rather than 'one API call per object version being deleted'.

As for the efficiency of the list manipulation, that runs fast so there's no real benefit to be gained by changing it.

I notice your check for `filtered_versions` that avoids situations like a Key of `foo/lunch` also matching `foo/lunchtime`. It's good you realised that potential problem.

An **alternative approach** that could be considered 'more efficient' would be to **copy the desired previous version to the same Key**, which would cause that data to be the 'current' version of the object. So, instead of 'deleting stuff since that version' you would be 'copying that version to also be the current version'. This way, you're never losing any versions and you could even 'roll-back' to newer versions later!

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, John - those do seem to improve the overall efficiency.  Too bad there is no way to avoid having to bring all the objects that share the prefix down to python to then filter it.  Maybe aws will add a "key" option to the bucket.object_versions.filter method soon.